# how to create and assign a value to a variable created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
function whatever(arg) {
  eval(arg) + '_group' = [];
}
```

The purpose is to have only 1 function instead having three with basically the same content but with different variable names.

At the end I want to have something like:

```
a_group = [];
b_group = [];
```

Doing this way, I'm getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

**EDIT**

Here is the original function that I'm trying to make work. But it won't work.

```
function collect_all_values_for(field_name) {

    switch(field_name) {
        case 'states':
            use = 'state';
        case 'cities':
            use = 'city';
        case 'neighborhoods':
            use = 'neighborhood';        
    }

    window[field_name + '_group'] = [];

    n_fields = $('[id^=' + use + '_]').length-1;

    i = 0;
    field_value = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<= n_fields; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            field_value = $('#' + use).val(); 
        }else{
            field_value = $('#' + use + '_id' + i).val();
        }

        //states_group.push(field_value);
        window[field_name + '_group'].push(field_value);
    }

}
```

Looking on the console output:

```
states_group
[undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

And then I should be able to call it as:

```
collect_all_values_for('states');
collect_all_values_for('cities');
collect_all_values_for('neighborhoods');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function whatever(arg) {
  window[arg + '_group'] = [];
}
```

This will set `a_group`, `b_group` as global variable.

To access those variable use:

`window['a_group'], window['b_group']` and so on.

#### According to edit

In your `switch` you should use `break;`.

```
switch(field_name) {
    case 'states':
        use = 'state';
        break;
    case 'cities':
        use = 'city';
        break;
    case 'neighborhoods':
        use = 'neighborhood';   
        break;     
}
```

### Using local Object *(without window object)* and better

```
var myObject = {};

function whatever(arg) {
  myObject[arg + '_group'] = [];
  // output: { 'a_group' : [], 'b_group' : [], .. }
}

// to set value
myObject[arg + '_group'].push( some_value );

// to get value
myObject[arg + '_group'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you really shouldn't use eval this should help

`eval(arg + '_group') = [];`

Answer (score 1):

Just to increase @theparadox's answer.
I prefer to use the following way to make a switch.

```
var options =  {
    'states' : 'state',
    'cities': 'city',
    'neighborhoods': 'neighborhood'    
};
use = options[field_name];
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2qbVC/)

Or if you just want to remove the last letter, you can do this.

`use = field_name.slice(0,-1);`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2qbVC/1/)

Comment: Nice! Didnt't know about this way. Thank you!